# Cant resolve variables in html

Tags: java, web, thymeleaf

I want to connect an input from my html page to MYSQL Database via a Controller:

```
<form th:action="@{/trainees/save}" method="post" th:object="${trainee}"
     style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

...

```
 <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control" required/>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/trainees/save")
public String saveTrainee(Trainee trainee){
    service.save(trainee);
    return "redirect:/trainees";
}
```

I have no errors at all but for some Reason in every html Document for the Variables "trainee" , "email", etc. he cannot create a connection and I get the "Cannot resolve" error.

Inspection info: Reports unresolved references and invalid Thymeleaf expressions.

I have tried to use different expressions like `th:value` instead of `th:field...`